# Erlang: How to open a file in a text editor

Tags: erlang

Is there a function to open a file in a text editor like gedit with erlang?
Suppose my program is running in my home directory `~` and the file is located at `~/file/path/test.txt`.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Like `cmd/1` from [`os` module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/os)?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that :)
Thank you

Comment: Also is there a way to know if the file was closed?

Comment: Ignore my answer, it doesn't work.